# how to add the watermark to Printer Command Language Document (PCL) file by PJL command?

Tags: command, watermark, pcl, pjl

Did @PJL command can add the watermark to the PCL file?

The official documentation didn't mention any information about the watermark.

I expects after adding the watermark to the PCL file, the program passes the PCL file to the printer and outputs the paper with the watermark

Comment: PCL (and PJL) are not PostScript, removed the PostScript tag.